# AIDL interface having different package name gives SecurityException

Tags: java, android, rpc, aidl

I have created two apps: app A and app B.

App B has a service and app A tries to make API calls to the service with using AIDL interface.

When I try:

```
boolean success = bindService(intent, mServiceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
```

This gives a 'true'. So, I am assuming that app A is bind with service in B.

However, when I attempt to call a method it gives:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Binder invocation to an incorrect interface
```

The reason of this is I have two different package names for each AIDL file.

On what approach should I take to solve this issue?

Comment: the aidl file you are trying to add should be placed with same package in your client app. Like if your AppA is com.foo1 and AppB is com.foo2, place aidl of AppA into AppB/app/src/main/aidl/com/foo1/ExampleAidl.aidl. This will work.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out making a Service JAR file and imported to the client side. But I will try with your approach. Thank you.

Comment: did it work? @jlee